# What is the difference between these two classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I don't know how they are different in css

```
something
{
   //some properties
}

something >.somethingelse
{
   // something else's properties
}
```

and

```
something
{
   //some properties
}

something .somethingelse
{
   // something else's properties
}
```

I don't know why there is such a `>` in the second case. Should there also be a `<` for use too ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014845/not-understanding-the-child-selector

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632954/parentchild-css-selector?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `>` indicates that direct children `somethingelse` are found under `something`. Otherwise descendants will be found at all levels.

So using this following example:

```
<div class="something">
    <div class="somethingelse">
        <div class="somethingelse">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the `>` example only the outer `somethingelse` div will take effect. For the example without `>` both divs will have the style applied.

`<` might imply a parent selector (ie apply a style to the direct parent of a matching class). I'm not aware of this existing yet, but theres an interesting post on it a csstricks [here](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/).

Comment: `Should there also be a < for use too ?` :)

Comment: @sabithpocker: in CSS4 [selector subjects](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-selectors4-20120823/#subject) are to be introduced. Basically you'd be able to match any element (not necessary the right-most) in a given relationship - e.g. `!p a` will match paragraphs that contain links. Note this is still a draft, I believe at one stage w3c intended to propose using `$` for subject selector

Comment: @o.v.: Yeah, and they haven't decided whether to use `!` yet, and if so whether to put it before or after the compound selector. `$` proved too confusing for people used to variable syntax from other languages.

Answer (score 3):

The `>` selects any element with the class `.somethingelse` which is a *child* of an element with the class `.something`.

The second CSS selector will select any *descendents* of the element with the class `.something`. I.e. the children, and the childrens children, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`>` selects direct descendants of `something` that have class `.somethingelse`

Currently there is no parent (`<`) selector in CSS